# How to make NVIDIA GEFORCE 710M a default graphics on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, ivybridge

Honestly, my default graphic driver for Ubuntu 13.10 is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile. But got a Nvidia driver which it was already been installed. So, how to make Nvidia driver as a default graphics driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your Nvidia optimus technology to save battery life, you could use Bumblebee from apt-get as Danatela said. Then, `optirun name-of-the-program` will allow you to set name-of-the-program program to run with your Nvidia GPU.

If you don't care about battery life, all you have to do is to switch from Nvidia Optimus to you Nvidia GEFORCE in the BIOS.